# Moq - how to initialize testing object once for multiple tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am trying to structure my unit test in such a way that if I change the constructor of the object being tested I don't have to change a lot of tests. Here is a simplified example of my set up right now:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    _mockedObject1.Setup(etc);
    _mockedObject2.Setup(etc);
    var service = new TestedService(_mockedObject1.Object, _mockedObject2.Object, ...,
        _mockedObject7.Object);

    //Act and Assert
}
```

Now I've got 20 unit tests that are arranged this same way. If I have to change the constructor of TestedService I have to go into all 20 tests and change the line that creates service. Can I pull this line of code out into TestInitialize or something so that I would only have to change it one time? My first thought is that I can't because then service would get created before my .Setups. Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: Do you use a DI container, like for instance Ninject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can pull the creation of your service before setting up the dependencies. The SetUp will still be bound to the mocked objects. You could try something like:

```
private TestedService service;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    this.service = new TestedService(_mockedObject1.Object, _mockedObject2.Object, ...,
        _mockedObject7.Object);
} 

[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    _mockedObject1.Setup(etc);
    _mockedObject2.Setup(etc);

    //Act and Assert
    this.service.Whatever(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Automoqing](https://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking) since you are already using Moq it would do what you want or even better. Simply it is Dependency Injection container that injects mocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize these objects in the function with a [ClassInitialize()] attribute. This is supposed to run before any tests within that class run.